# ValueError Converting UTC time to a desired format and time zone python

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

I am trying to convert UTC time to a normal format and timezone. The docs are making me throw toys!! Can someone please write me a quick simple example. My code in python;

```
m.startAt = datetime.strptime(r['StartAt'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```

**Error**

> > ValueError: time data '2016-10-28T12:42:59.389Z' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `datetime.strptime` to work you need to specify a formatting string **appropriately matching** the string you're parsing from. The error indicates you don't - so parsing fails. See [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for the formatting arguments.

The string you get is indicated in the error message: `'2016-10-28T12:42:59.389Z'` (a `Z`/`Zulu`/ISO 8601 datetime string).

The matching string for that would be `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'` or, after dropping the final Z from the string, `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'`.

A bit tricky is the final `Z` in the string, which can be parsed by a `%z`, but which may not be supported in the GAE-supported python version (in my 2.7.12 it's not supported):

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2016-10-28T12:42:59.389', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 324, in _strptime
    (bad_directive, format))
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

So I stripped `Z` and used the other format:

```
>>> stripped_z = '2016-10-28T12:42:59.389Z'[:-1]
>>> stripped_z
'2016-10-28T12:42:59.389'
>>> that_datetime = datetime.strptime(stripped_z, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> that_datetime
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 28, 12, 42, 59, 389000)
```

To obtain a string use `strftime`:

```
>>> that_datetime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
'28/10/2016 12:42'
```

It'll be more complicated if you want to use a timezone, but my recommendation is to stick with UTC on the backend storage and leave timezone conversion for the frontend/client side.

You might want to use a `DateTimeProperty` to store the value, in which case into you can write it directly:

```
entity.datetime_property = that_datetime
```

Comment: I competely get that. I'm new to datetime. I need to find out how to format that string into a readable date object like 28/10/2016 to send to the datastore

Comment: absolutely correct on the edit. Worked. Thanks a mill.

Answer (score 0):

That error is telling you the problem, the format string has to match the datetime string you gave it.

For example:

```
x = datetime.strptime("2016-6-9 08:57", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Notice the second string matches the format of the first one.

Your time string looks like this:

2016-10-28T12:42:59.389Z

Which does not match your format string.

Comment: I competely get that. I'm new to datetime. I need to find out how to format that string into a readable date object like 28/10/2016 to send to the datastore